# Cannot Start Odoo Server

Tags: python-3.6

When I try to start odoo server, I get this error :

File "/home/anas/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dateutil/tz/tz.py", line 21, in 
    from six.moves import _thread
ImportError: cannot import name '_thread'

Comment: https://github.com/opencobra/cobrapy/issues/490

Comment: pip uninstall python-dateutil
pip install python-dateutil --upgrade

Comment: I tried this but still having the same error !

Comment: Problem resolved with : sudo pip3 uninstall requests
sudo pip3 install requests==2.20.0

Comment: You can answer your own question, so other people can see it